# If $L$ is ample, $A$ a line bundle, what is the growth of $q(k)$ such that $L^{q(k)}\otimes A^k$ is ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $L$ is an ample line bundle, and $A$ is any line bundle, on a smooth variety. For a fixed $k$, there is a smallest $q(k)$ such that $L^{q(k)}\otimes A^k$ is ample. How does this function $q(k)$ grow in $k$?

I think there should be some expression for $q(k)$ in terms of the geometry of the ample cone, but I am not sure what it is exactly.

Comment: Isn't it clear that the growth is linear in $k$? If $\ell, a$ are the corresponding vectors in $NS(X)\otimes \mathbb{R}$ and $C$ is the ample cone, let $\lambda = \inf \{ x \, : x\ell + a \in C \}$. Then $q(k)$ is between $k\lambda$ and $k\lambda + 1$, since for $q = \lceil \lambda \rceil + 1$, $q \ell + a$ is in the interior of $C$ while $(q-1) \ell + a$ is not.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Yes I agree. Shoud've thought about it a bit more before posting. Thanks!